# Nested dictionary from 3 different length lists in Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I want to make a nested Dictionary out of three different lists which are unequal in length.

These are the lists.

```
jaren = ['2017', '2018']
wedstrijden = ['NED', 'GER', 'GBR', 'USA']
eventresults = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [1,2], [1,2,3,4,5,6], [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10], [3,2,1], [6,5,4,3,2,1], [4,5,6,3], [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]]
```

The output should be like:

```
main_dict = {'2017': {'NED':[1, 2, 3, 4], 'GER':[1,2], 'GBR':[1,2,3,4,5,6], 'USA':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]},{'2018': {'NED':[3, 2, 1], 'GER':[6,5,4,3,2,1], 'GBR':[4,5,6,3], 'USA':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]}}
```

My current output is:

```
main_dict = {'2017': {'NED':[1, 2, 3, 4], 'GER':[1, 2, 3, 4], 'GBR':[1, 2, 3, 4], 'USA':[1, 2, 3, 4]},{'2018': {'NED':[1,2], 'GER':[1,2], 'GBR':[1,2], 'USA':[1,2]}}
```

And I use this code:

```
main_dict = {}
for jaar, eventresult in zip(jaren, eventresults):
    main_dict[jaar] = {}
        for wedstrijd in wedstrijden:
            main_dict[jaar][wedstrijd] = eventresult
```

Actually my list eventresults is a list of DataFrames instead of lists with integers.

Can someone give me a help with the code?

Comment: If you have a dataframe, why the loops here? You can just group your dataframe instead and add these columns to begin with.

Comment: And how are those nested lists actually stored in the dataframe? They are not of equal length, so presumably they are Python list objects in cells of a series?

Comment: I wanted to sort the Datarames (which are rowing results) to year and event. Each DataFrame is a specific event at a regatta in a specific year.

Comment: Each regatta has got a different number of events, participants and races.

Answer (score 1):

This is easily solved by [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip)ping `wedstrijden` with an [iterator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#iterator-types) over `eventresults`:

```
event_itr = iter(eventresults)
result = {}
for year in jaren:
    result[year] = dict(zip(wedstrijden, event_itr))

# result:
# {'2017': {'NED': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'GER': [1, 2], 'GBR': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 'USA': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]},
#  '2018': {'NED': [3, 2, 1], 'GER': [6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1], 'GBR': [4, 5, 6, 3], 'USA': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]}}
```

Comment: Also the comprehension `event_itr = ...; {year: dict(zip(..., event_itr) for year in jaren}`.

Comment: Thank you, it looks easy and it is easy. I am nrelative new to python. So thank you very much!